# Circular Doubly LinkedList ListIterator

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

This is a homework question. I have a Double Linked Node class, Circular Double Linked List class which implements `Iterable`, and a Iterator class that implements Iterator. I understand the concept of an iterator where an implicit cursor sits between two nodes and on a call to `next()` it returns the node it just jumped over. I created a test class with a new list object. I then created an iterator and called next, I received the correct `No Such Element exception` but when I added some nodes to the list I received a `Null Pointer Exception` instead of it returning the last returned node. How can I correct this?

My Node class:

```
public class DoubleLinkedNode<E>{
private E data;

private DoubleLinkedNode<E> next;

private DoubleLinkedNode<E> prev;


public DoubleLinkedNode(E data, DoubleLinkedNode<E> next, DoubleLinkedNode<E> prev){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}
/**
 * Used to construct a node that points to null for its prev and next.
 * @param data Data is a generic variable to be stored in the node.
 */
public DoubleLinkedNode(E data){
    this(data, null, null);
} 


//getters
public E getData(){
    return data;
}

public DoubleLinkedNode<E> getNext(){
    return next;
}

public DoubleLinkedNode<E> getPrev(){
    return prev;
}
//setters
public void setData(E data){
    this.data = data;
}

public void setNext(DoubleLinkedNode<E> next){
    this.next = next;
}

public void setPrev(DoubleLinkedNode<E> prev){
    this.prev = prev;
}

@Override public String toString(){
    if(data == null){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return data.toString();
    }
}

}
```

The List class with the private inner Iterator class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class CircularDoubleLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E>{

private int size;   
private DoubleLinkedNode<E> head;


public CircularDoubleLinkedList(){
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;      
}       
/**
 * Adds an item to the end of the list.
 * 
 * @param data The Data that is to be stored in the node.
 */ 
public void add(E data){    
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> newNode = new DoubleLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if(this.head == null){
        newNode.setNext(newNode);
        newNode.setPrev(newNode);
        this.head = newNode;
        this.size++;
        //if list is empty create a new node and insert
    }
    else{
        DoubleLinkedNode<E> temp = this.head.getPrev();
        this.head.getPrev().setNext(newNode);
        this.head.setPrev(newNode);
        newNode.setPrev(temp);
        newNode.setNext(this.head);     
        this.size++;
    }
}
/**
 * Which adds an item at the specified index.
 * 
 * @param index The index in which the new Node is added. 
 * @param data The data which is to be stored in the node.
 */
public void add(int index, E data){
    int currIndex = 0;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> currNode = this.head;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> nextNode = this.head.getNext();
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> prevNode = this.head.getPrev();
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> newNode = new DoubleLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if(index == 0){
        prevNode.setNext(newNode);
        currNode.setPrev(newNode);
        newNode.setPrev(prevNode);
        newNode.setNext(currNode);
        this.head = newNode;
        this.size++;    
    }
    else if (index > 0){        
        while(currIndex != this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex++;
                currNode = currNode.getNext();
                nextNode = nextNode.getNext();
                prevNode = prevNode.getNext();                  
            }else{              
                newNode.setPrev(prevNode);
                newNode.setNext(currNode);
                prevNode.setNext(newNode);
                currNode.setPrev(newNode);
                currNode = newNode;
                this.size++;
                break;                                      
            }
        }       
    }
    else if (index < 0){
        while(currIndex != -this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex--;
                currNode = currNode.getPrev();
                prevNode = prevNode.getPrev();
                nextNode = nextNode.getPrev();
            }else{              
                newNode.setNext(nextNode);
                newNode.setPrev(currNode);
                currNode.setNext(newNode);
                nextNode.setPrev(newNode);          
                currNode = newNode;
                this.size++;
                break;                                      
            }
        }   
    }
}
/**
 * Returns the data stored at the specified index.
 * 
 * @param index The index determines the node whose data is returned.
 * @return Returns the data of the node at the index.
 */
public E get(int index){//returns the data stored at the specified index
    int currIndex = 0;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> currNode = this.head;
    E temp = null;      
    if(index == 0){//zero case          
        temp = currNode.getData();
    }
    else if(index > 0){//positive           
        while(currIndex != this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex++;
                currNode = currNode.getNext();                              
            }else{                              
                temp = currNode.getData();
                break;                                      
            }
        }   
    }
    else if(index < 0){//negative       
        while(currIndex != -this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex--;
                currNode = currNode.getPrev();
            }else{              
                temp = currNode.getData();
                break;                                      
            }
        }           
    }
    return temp;
}   
/**
 * Which removes and returns an item from the list.
 * 
 * @param index Removes the node at the current index.
 * @return Returns the data of the removed node.
 */
public E remove(int index){//which removes and returns an item from the list
    int currIndex = 0;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> currNode = this.head;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> nextNode = this.head.getNext();
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> prevNode = this.head.getPrev();
    E temp = null;  
    if(index == 0){
        temp = currNode.getData();
        prevNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
        nextNode.setPrev(currNode.getPrev());
        this.head = nextNode;
        size--;
    }
    else if(index > 0){//positive           
        while(currIndex != this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex++;
                currNode = currNode.getNext();
                nextNode = nextNode.getNext();
                prevNode = prevNode.getNext();                  
            }else{                              
                temp = currNode.getData();
                prevNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
                nextNode.setPrev(currNode.getPrev());
                currNode = nextNode;
                size--;
                break;                                      
            }
        }   
    }
    else if(index < 0){//negative       
        while(currIndex != -this.size){
            if(currIndex != index%size){
                currIndex--;
                currNode = currNode.getPrev();
                prevNode = prevNode.getPrev();
                nextNode = nextNode.getPrev();
            }else{              
                temp = currNode.getData();
                prevNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
                nextNode.setPrev(currNode.getPrev());
                currNode = prevNode;
                size--;
                break;                                      
            }
        }           
    }
    return temp;
} 
/**
 * Returns the size.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int size(){
    return size;
}
@Override public String toString(){
    String str = "[";
    int index = 0;
    DoubleLinkedNode<E> curr = head;
    if(size == 0){
        return "There is no one here to kill.";         
    }else{      
        while (index <this.size) {
            str += curr.getData();  
            curr = curr.getNext();
            index++;
                if (index<this.size) {
                    str += ", ";
                }
        }
            str += "]";
    }
    return str;
  } 
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return new CircularDoubleIterator();
}   
// Iterator inner class begins
private class CircularDoubleIterator implements ListIterator<E> {

    private DoubleLinkedNode<E> nextItem;//reference to next item
    private int index = 0;
    private DoubleLinkedNode<E> lastReturned;// the last node to be returned by prev() or next()
                                            // reset to null after a remove() or add()

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if(!hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element.");
        }
        else{
                            nextItem = head; //edited 11Sept13
            lastReturned = nextItem.getNext();
            nextItem = nextItem.getNext();
                            head = nextItem; //edited 11Sept13
            index++;
            return lastReturned.getData();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public E previous() {
        if(!hasPrevious()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element.");
        }
        else{       

        index--;

        return ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int nextIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int previousIndex() {
        return index-1;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean hasNext() {  
        return size != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {      
        return size!= 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void remove() {
    }

    @Override
    public void set(E theData) {
        if(lastReturned == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        else{
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void add(E theData) {
        if(size == 0){              
        }
        else if(size != 0){
        }

    }

}

//Iterator inner class ends
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you assign values to `private DoubleLinkedNode<E> nextItem;` when you create iterator.
I cannot see the whole code. So I assume that `nextItem` is null or its `next` field is null.

Comment: Ok, I set nextItem to head in the next(), the next() method returns the first element but calling next element returns the same element. Looks like with every next() call it resets nextItem to head.

Comment: Ah ok! I then set head to nextItem before I returned the lastReturned. It works, thanks for bringing the unassigned nextItem to my attention!